# WiX installer getting error: Failed to perform minor upgrade of MSI package

Tags: .net, wix

I have a WiX installer, and we've managed to upgrade it from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.3 without any problems, till now.

I had to make some changes to our exe, so to release this new version, I increased the version to 1.0.0.4, but it seems that some users who are installing it are getting these errors:

```
[34A0:34C0][2017-04-20T09:06:44]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to perform minor upgrade of MSI package.
[34A0:34C0][2017-04-20T09:06:44]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[350C:059C][2017-04-20T09:06:44]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[350C:059C][2017-04-20T09:06:44]i319: Applied execute package: Setup, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[350C:059C][2017-04-20T09:06:44]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

I'm sure what is going on, why did it fail to perform minor upgrade of the MSI package.

Also, currently this error is only seen for some users, not for all users.

Please advise.

Comment: Google returns quite a few results for 0x80070643... Enable Windows Installer verbose logging and check Windows event log which might have more error details.

Comment: I have generally found that when creating upgrade installers you need to increment the 3rd part of the version number as WiX seems to ignore the 4th part.  i.e. Version number 1.0.0.3 is the same as 1.0.0.4 as far as WiX is concerned.

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 So, I released a new version 1.0.1, and I still get the same error :(